# why am i not able to assign and getting an error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' slow.next=fast.next

Tags: python, singly-linked-list, attributeerror

```
class Solution:
def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: Optional[ListNode], n: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    temp=head
    cnt=0
    while temp:
        temp=temp.next
        cnt+=1
    m=cnt-n
    temp=head.next
    curr=head
    for i in range(m-1):
        print(i)
        temp=temp.next
        curr=curr.next
    print(curr)
    print(temp)

    curr.next=temp.next

    return head
```

how can i correct this code im not getting any idea?

error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
slow.next=fast.next

Comment: I don't see `slow.next=fast.next` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.
Check for slow and fast as non-None before using `.next` with them, or temp and curr as per your current case.